# Thread output when print/puts called inside thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, stdout

My Attempt at creating a simple animated shell spinner guy...

```
STDOUT.sync

# spinner stuff
spinner_running = false
chars = ['|', '/', '-', '\\']
@spinner = Thread.new do
  loop do
    unless spinner_running
      Thread.stop
      print "\b"
    end
    print chars[0]
    sleep(1)
    print "\b"
    chars.push chars.shift
  end
end

def start_spinner
  spinner_running = true
  @spinner.wakeup
end

def stop_spinner
  spinner_running = false
end

print ".......X"

start_spinner()
sleep(5)
stop_spinner()
```

Just trying to create a simple spinner, and yes, I know there's a gem for that...

Why wouldn't I be seeing the progress of the spinner while it's executing in this code?

**Current Output: `ruby spinner.rb`**

```
.......X< new prompt (no new line) >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spinner_running` needs to be `@spinner_running`.

It's first defined as a local variable and then used in the thread, which is fine as the block will have access to the scope it's defined in. However the `start_` and `stop_` `spinner` methods define their own scope, so when `spinner_running` is used there it is a newly defined, local variable.

So the `spinner_running` used by the thread is never set to true - so the thread exits straight away when it is run.

To fix it, it needs to be made into an instance variable by prefixing it with `@`.

In answer to your comment, I don't think there's an easy way for the thread to spot this - because the bug isn't in the thread.

Comment: Yes this gets at the heart of what was wrong, there were some scoping errors that was being hidden by the thread failing silently... any way to detect these errors on the thread?

Comment: I don't think the thread failed - it did exactly what you told it to!

Comment: Hmm, I can't think of a way for the thread to detect there's an error - but on the plus side this particular bug is never going to work by accident in testing and then fail in production, that I can see.

Comment: By the way I don't mean to patronise you with the simple explanation, just thought it would be useful for others who may come to this question later.